# Как отрендерить отфильтрованные элементы вместо отрендеренного стейта?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, render

Есть у меня вот такой вот компонент, который должен фильтровать айтемы по категориям при нажатии на соответствующий фильтр. Сделано все, кроме, собственно, рендера. У меня есть объект, который нужно отрендерить, но я не знаю как. Вернее не знаю как его отрендерить вместо уже зарендеренных айтемов со стейта

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'

import Items from '../items'
import Filters from '../filters'
import Service from '../../services'

export default class Shop extends Component {

    KubicService = new Service()

    state = {
        items: {},
        filters: {}
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        this.KubicService.getCategories()
        .then((result) => {
            this.setState({
                filters: result.data
            })
        })

        this.KubicService.postCatalog()
        .then((result) => {
            this.setState({
                items: result.data
            })
        })
    }

    render(){
            
        let filterItems = {}

        const onFilterClick = (e) => {
            const cats = {...this.state.filters}
            const itemId = e.target.id
            if(itemId === 'all') {
                console.log(cats)
            } else if(itemId !== 'all') {
                console.log(cats[itemId].name, cats[itemId].id)
                const items  = this.state.items
                for(let key in items) {
                    if(items[key].category.id == cats[itemId].id) {
                        console.log('false')
                        filterItems[key] = items[key]
                        console.log(filterItems)
                    } else {
                        console.log('true')
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }

        return(
            <div>
                <Filters onFilterClick = { onFilterClick }/>
                <Items items = {this.state.items} />
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Вот код "Items"

```
import React from 'react'

const Items = (props) => {

        const arr = Array.from(props.items)

        const elements = arr.map((item, index) => {
            let url = ''
            if(item && item.preview_image) {
                url = 'http://*********'
                url = url + item.preview_image
            }
            return (
                <div key={index} className='store-item'>
                    <img className='store-item__img' src={url} alt='item img'></img>
                    <h3 className='store-item__title'>{item.name}</h3>
                    <h3 className='store-item_price'>${item.price}</h3>
                </div>
            )
        })
        
        return (
            <div className='store-items'>
                { elements }            
            </div>
        )
    }

export default Items
```

А вот код "Filters"

```
import React from 'react'

const Filters = (props) => {

        return(
            <div className='store-filters'>
                <div className='filter-category'>
                    <div className='categories'>
                    <button className='category-all is-active btn' id='all' onClick={ props.onFilterClick }>all</button>
                    <button className='category-mac btn' id='0' onClick={ props.onFilterClick }>mac</button>
                    <button className='category-macbook btn' id='1' onClick={ props.onFilterClick }>macbook</button>
                    <button className='category-iphone btn' id='2' onClick={ props.onFilterClick }>iphone</button>
                    <button className='category-ipad btn' id='3' onClick={ props.onFilterClick }>ipad</button>
                    <button className='category-watch btn' id='4' onClick={ props.onFilterClick }>watch</button>
                    <button className='category-airpods btn' id='5' onClick={ props.onFilterClick }>airpods</button>
                    </div>
                    <select className="filter">
                        <option className='filter-variable'>Price: high to low</option>
                        <option className='filter-variable'>Price: low to high</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }

export default Filters
```

Прошу помочь, ибо не знаю как такое даже загуглить

Answer (score 0):

В чем проблема в Items передавать не весь массив элементов, а уже отфильтрованный, в соответствии с активным фильтром? (см. пример и комменты ниже)

```js
export default class Shop extends Component {
    //ваш код
    render(){
        //фильтруем
        const filteredItems = this.state.items.filter((item)=>/*ваш фильтр*/)
      
        //ф-ю надо вынести в тело компонента, в рендере ей делать нечего
        const onFilterClick = (e) => {
           //должен просто устанавливать новый активный фильтр в стейте
           this.setState({...this.state, filter: /*новое значение*/})
        }
        
        //в Items передаем уже отфильтрованные айтемы
        return(
            <div>
                <Filters onFilterClick = { onFilterClick }/>
                <Items items = {filteredItems} /> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

Кроме этого, вы зачем-то руками прописываете категории в компоненте `Filters`, но получаете их из вне в компоненте Shop. Вам нужно полученные в `Shop` фильтры передавать в компонент `Filters` и уже исходя из категорий делать кнопки. (это, кстати, упростит установку активного фильтра в `Shop`. См. пример.

```js
export default class Shop extends Component {
    KubicService = new Service()
    
    state = {
        items: {},
        filters: {},
        activeFilter: 'all' //в стейте теперь также находится текущий активный фильтр
    }
    //теперь ф-я получает не ивент, а новый активный фильтр
    onFilterClick = (activeFilter) => {
           this.setState({...this.state, filter: activeFilter})
    }
    
    componentDidMount() {/*ваш код*/}

        render(){
        const filteredItems = this.state.items.filter((item)=>/*ваш фильтр*/)
        
        //Filters получает также и список имеющихся фильтров (categories)
        return(
            <div>
                <Filters categories={this.state.filters} onFilterClick = { onFilterClick }/>
                <Items items = {filteredItems} /> 
            </div>
        )
    }
}



const Filters = (props) => {

        return(
            <div className='store-filters'>
                <div className='filter-category'>
                    <div className='categories'>
                      {/*здесь получаете из props категории*/
                        props.categories.map(filter=>{
                          return <button onClick={()=>props.onFilterClick(filter) /*здесь устанавливаете новый фильтр при клике*/}>
                            {filter}
                          </button>
                        })
                      
                      }
                    </div>
                    <select className="filter">
                        <option className='filter-variable'>Price: high to low</option>
                        <option className='filter-variable'>Price: low to high</option>
                    </select>
                </div>
            </div>
        )
    }
```